# How do I make a channel name on YouTube not my first and last name?

Tags: youtube

how do I change my channel name on YouTube

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options under [account settings](https://www.youtube.com/account):

1. Click "Edit on Google" to change your account first and last name.[Docs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964)
2. Click "Create a new channel" and then create a channel with a specific name that you want and add new content there. [Docs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861)